# mantaining referential integrity across multiple tables

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

[image: See my diagram here]

I have the following problem: A customer can have 2 type of resources: servers and domains. A server can serve multiple domains and a domain can be allocated to multiple servers but a customer has a fixed set of servers and domains allocated to him. The customer can edit the domain-server-mapping table directly. How can I prevent the customer from allocating servers which do not belong to him, in other words how can I make sure that a domain and server inserted in domain-server-mapping have the same customer primary key?

Comment: In this schema it is supposed than either `Domains` and `Servers` has a `customer_id` reference, does it?

Comment: A server can be used by several customers or only by one customer?

Comment: @McNets Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Renzo A server can be used by only a customer. Sorry for the example it's a bit contrived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add too many redundant (and for this reason dangerous) foreign keys to solve your problem. It is sufficient to use a normalized schema, like for instance:

```
create table Customers 
( 
    customer_id int primary key
);

create table Domains 
(
    domain_id int primary key,
    customer_id int references Customers
);

create table Servers
(
    server_id int primary key,
    customer_id int references Customers
);

create table Domain_Server_Mapping
(
    domain_id int references Domains,
    server_id int references Servers,
    primary key(domain_id, server_id)
);
```

Then you can add a trigger that prevent the insertion or update of the table `Domain_Server_Mapping` with servers and domains that belong to different customers, as well as check inside the application if the server and domain modified belong to the current customer.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion and according to your schema, you should add a multi-column FK either for `Customer/Servers` and `Customer/Domains`

```
create table Customers 
( 
    customer_id int primary key
);

create table Domains 
(
    customer_id int references Customers(customer_id),
    domain_id int,
    primary key(customer_id, domain_id)
);

create table Servers
(
    customer_id int references Customers(customer_id),
    server_id int,
    primary key(customer_id, server_id)
);

create table DomainsServers
(
    customer_id int references Customers(customer_id),
    domain_id int,
    server_id int,
    primary key(customer_id, domain_id, server_id),
    foreign key fk_domains (customer_id, domain_id) references Domains(customer_id, domain_id),
    foreign key fk_servers (customer_id, server_id) references Servers(customer_id, server_id),
);
```